# How Does STM32 Factory Bootloader Allow for Reflashing at any Time?

Tags: arm, embedded, stm32, bootloader, flash-memory

I'm aware that on some STM32 boards, they come with a built in bootloader in their ROM. Quoting from [STM32 Application Note](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/CD00167594.pdf)

> The bootloader is stored in the internal boot ROM (system memory) of STM32 devices, and is
> programmed by ST during production. Its main task is to download the application program to the
> internal Flash memory through one of the available serial peripherals (such as USART, CAN,
> USB, I2C, SPI).

However the ability to reflash at any time, i.e. trigger a reflash when your board is a running a program confuses me. My understanding is that a bootloader is the first piece of code to execute and then launches your user program. However, to facilitate this flashing at any time, won't the bootloader have to constantly poll for a request to reflash?

Comment: In the section you have quoted, where does it mention "anytime"?  You seem to have become confused by your own invention, or you have not quoted the part that has confused you.

Comment: @Clifford Say I am using the STM32CubeProgrammer or ST-Flash connected to the board with a mini-USB. I have not modified any BOOT pins, i.e using factory settings. I hit 'enter' to commence the flashing (which I can do at any time). What software is facilitating this transfer? I thought it was this bootloader based on what I quoted.

Comment: Not at the any time, you must either https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/312380 (eg. reinitialize everything and jump to the bootloader entry point), or reset mcu into the boot section (that can happen at any time), or you can have own bootloader in program flash

Comment: yes, at any time you can pull the reset line with the boot pin(s) asserted as desired and boot the chip into the bootloader from which you can then (re)program the part.   yes you can do this any time you wish.  there is no magic here, and is documented....

Comment: the newer parts stm32g and some others, are moving away from this.  with the application flash erased they will still boot into the bootloader without the need for the boot pins, but once programmed, you cannot get into the bootloader using boot pins from a virgin part, you have to modify some non volatile control registers.   the bootloader is still there, and with modification can still be used.....for now....but as with atmel I think the writing is on the wall...

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is right. Almost.

In case of STM32, you need to set up the chip to run the bootloader, typically using BOOT pins. When the bootloader runs, it checks if the programming is necessary by monitoring the specific peripherals. If the programming is not triggered, it jumps to the user program.

Therefore, you cannot reprogram at any time, only at boot time.

Here is an example bootloader flowchart for programming over UART or I2C.

[image]

See this [application note on STM32 bootloader](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/cd00167594-stm32-microcontroller-system-memory-boot-mode-stmicroelectronics.pdf) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

The bootloader only polls for an update on start-up/reset.  So not "anytime" in the sense of "spontaneously" - you do have to trigger it.  If the programmer has access to the reset pin or control of power, it can of course invoke a restart.

Moreover the ROM bootloader only runs at all if the BOOT pins are set appropriatlely.  The boot modes are Flash, SRAM or ROM.

Comment: Without knowing the board, it is not possible to tell. It could implement an SWD or JTAG connection, or the board may have a bootloader in flash. mbed compatible boards present a mass storage device to which you simply copy the code and reboot.  The point is the boot ROM, is only one means of bootstrapping an STM32.  In 12 years of STM32 use, I have never used it - programming flash either via SWD/JTAG, or via my own bootloader resident in flash.

Comment: I see. Digging deeper, I've noticed that most of the boards I have used have a ICDI chip that exposes SWD via USB. This additional chip is what distinguishes them as evaluation boards I suppose. e.g. Texas Instruments have what they call Stellaris ICDI and STM32 have ST-Link ICDI, etc.